# Handle the cases when users input all one-of optional paramaters in API response

Tags: rest

An API endpoint I wrote supports two one-of parameters, and users are requested to supply values for one of them only, but ideally, they should not specify both.

```
{"A": "something", "B": "something"}
```

When users do not supply any of the two, an exception will be thrown.

However, I'm wondering how I should handle the scenarios when users put in values for both.

For the context, A is, loosely speaking, a subset of B. There's two opinions with my teammate:

1. When users input both, A shall prevail.
2. When users input both, a 400 exception is thrown to remind the users that we only need one of the two.

Thanks!

Comment: All depend if you want a default in case (1), if you well write your client code, only hacking attempt should be able to send both values. The choice (2) for me is better because I like to prevent all case like it does, it's easier to debug and you know what you really want and what is permit or not. If you choose default value, write it somewhere to not surprising your users. We can ask, why throw an Exception for none and not for all !? same case for me. Default or exceptions. It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'm wondering how I should handle the scenarios when users put in values for both.

You could look to media types as an analog.

That is, suppose we had a specification for `application/vnd.example.AorB+json`, which defined the A field, the B field, and explicitly expressed that exactly one of those two options should be present.

Now when our endpoint gets a POST, or a PUT, with content-type `application/vnd.example.AorB+json`, we know the entity included in the body of the request should be a json document with additional constraints on the keys and values.

So by analogy, if the keys and values are wrong, our endpoint should reject the document in the same way that it would if the JSON structure itself were not well formed.

If you buy that logic, then the practical answer is to deploy an endpoint that expects json, send it something broken, and see what response you get back.  Then model your own design on that.

The WebDAV standard has an interesting discussion related to its definition of the [422 status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2).

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

So you might look at your situation, and try to decide whether including both elements is "syntactically correct" or not, and choose the matching status code.

*In practice*, it really doesn't matter very much.  You SHOULD be explaining the specific problem [in the body of the response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5), so human beings can figure it out what happened.  The different status codes are really meta data, so that generic components can figure out what to do -- but there isn't anything in the standard that tells generic components to handle a `422` differently from a `400`.

So don't over think it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's reasonable/meaningful to expect one property, you should only allow one property.

Strict APIs are helpful because they guide users much better to what the intent of the server and resource is.

One great tool for this kind of stuff, is to use something like json-schema to specify exactly what your server does and does not expect. Being able to specify that only 1 out of 2 properties can appear is one of its features.